# R scp and unzip - invalid zip name argument

Tags: r, zip, scp

I wonder if anyone can help me - I am trying to download a file using scp and then unzip it (it is a set of 100 files, so they have to be zipped and as well it excludes unz)

Basically first I run

```
x <- scp(host = "WM.net", path = "/wmdata.zip", user = "w", password =  "wm")
```

it returns a raw object (of course it is a dummy address, you would not get anything, I cannot provide working site you can scp anything)

```
> class(x)
[1] "raw"
```

then I try to unzip it

```
b<-unzip(x)
Error in unzip(x) : invalid zip name argument
```

I tried to decompress it in memory but with no luck - the output is still raw, not a file list

```
z<-memDecompress(x, type = "unknown")
> class(z)
[1] "raw"
```

Where is my error? What am  doing wrong? I have a vague feeling I need to save x to disc as zip, and then use unzip, but no idea how to save raw compressed value.

EDIT: I tried as well saving as a binary file via

```
f<-file("file.bin",open="wb") #or f<-file("file.zip",open="wb")
writeBin(x, f)
b <- unzip(f) #or b <- unzip("file.bin") or b <- unzip("file.zip")
```

and it produced a file after the first line, but after the second line the file is still empty and the unzip procedure returns the same zip name error

```
> class(f)
[1] "file"       "connection"
> f
A connection with                      
description "file.zip"
class       "file"    
mode        "wb"      
text        "binary"  
opened      "opened"  
can read    "no"      
can write   "yes"
```

Comment: `memDecompress()` only works on raw streams that were compressed with  "gzip", "bzip2" or "xz" algorithms. `zip` is a completely different type and Tim's answer is the right one

Comment: _Please_ _read_ R documentation. That wld have told you the info in my previous comment _and_ it would tell you that the parameter to `unzip` is expected to be `The pathname of the zip file: tilde expansion (see path.expand) will be performed.`. You passed it a `connection` object. The documentation is there for a reason.

Comment: hrbrmstr - that was very helpful, please note I informed about memDecompress to avoid anyone pointing in this direction - I do know it does not apply to zip. And if you read my post instead of patronizing 'documentation is for a reason' you would notice that I passed the pathname to the procedure - without tilde it should mean current working directory. the file is there but it is empty - nothing unzip and your tilde can do about (i passed the path in #or b <- unzip("file.bin") or b <- unzip("file.zip"))

Comment: you didn't explain why you used `memCompress` so perhaps also read how to make a good question. `file()` objects aren't strings, so you really didn't pass in the expected parameter type. So, i'll continue to ask you to read documentation. `x <- RCurl::scp("mylocaalserver", "~/file.zip", user="bob") ; writeBin(x, "file.zip") ; (unzip("file.zip"))` has a lovely file list in output on my system so you are clearly missing something.

Comment: thank you, your last post resolved my query - instead of connection I can write straight to the filename provided, the critical here was avoiding file()

Comment: @hrbrmstr Please post that as an answer so that I may delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is not unexpected at all, because `unzip` expects a file as its first parameter, and you are trying to pass a raw R vector, which is a vector of bytes.  You can try first writing that raw vector to file, and then reading it using `unzip`.  Something like this:

```
x <- scp(host = "WM.net", path = "/wmdata.zip", user = "w", password =  "wm")
f <- file("path/to/your/file.bin", "wb")
writeBin(x, f)
b <- unzip(f)
```

This is not tested, but I wanted to point out the issues with how you were using the various APIs.

Comment: I tried your solution and while of course it is a right direction, it has to be a file, but it still returns the same 'invalid zip name argument' error. I tried it both with unzip(f) and unzip("file.bin") and unzip(file.zip"). The file line produces an empty file, but after writeBin the file is still 0 bytes (and empty). It does not though return any errors until it gets to unzip

Comment: @Slav I will leave this up until you get a full answer.  Then I'll delete it.